# In WPF, how can I handle an event in an ItemsControl ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, event-handling, controltemplate

I'm trying to handle an event inside an ItemsControl ControlTemplate. I have assigned the MouseUp and MouseDown events of a button (btnRight below). The problem is that when I click on the button, the event never reaches my code-behind. How do events in ControlTemplates work and what do I need to do to hook this up? I've tried assigning the events to the button in code-behind during the OnApplyTemplate event to no avail.

Thanks for your help!

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btnLeft" Grid.Column="0" Height="36">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images\left.png" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black" Padding="6">
                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MarginOffset}" />
            </Border>
            <Button x:Name="btnRight" Grid.Column="2" Height="36" MouseUp="btnRight_MouseUp" MouseDown="btnRight_MouseDown">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images\right.png" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the buttons? Are you trying to define logic within the items control? If so you may be taking the wrong approach. A control template is only meant for changing the look of a control, not changing its behaviour. Post some more detail about what you are trying to achieve and I could possibly help further.

Comment: I have created a custom control that extends ItemsControl; I am trying to define logic in the button clicks. I believe this is a valid approach. Items control already does a lot of stuff I'm trying to do so I may as well use it.

Comment: Sounds like *inheritance for/of implementation* to me. A better approach IMO would be to create a control which composites the ItemsControl with some buttons rather than trying to modify the behaviour of the ItemsControl using inheritance (especially via the ControlTemplate which is purely a mechanism for changing the appearance of a control)...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Definitely the way to go ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using button click events, create a new Command, bind the Command property of the Button to the Command you created, and then add a CommandBinding to your user control to handle the command when it is executed.

See [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands) [for](http://www.dev102.com/2008/12/10/using-command-binding-to-enhance-any-wpf-control/) more information.

Comment: Do you know of a list of all the various input gestures? I'm trying to find one ...

Comment: Answered my own question; I was actually looking for the Mouse Actions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseaction.aspx